# How do you get the length of an array that is in the state of an ngrx component store?

Tags: ngrx-store

If I have a state object that contains the state below, what is the correct way to get the length of the users array in the state?

Do I need to create a selector for this?

```
userLength$ = this.select(state => state.users.length);
```

Basically, on my view I would like to be able to show the number of users;

```
 <span>There are {{userLength}} users</span>
 //or something like
 <span>There are {{users$.length}} users</span>
```

```
export const initialState: UserState = {
  users: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      name: 'Dean'
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      name: 'John'
    }
  ],
  selectedUserId: null
}

//selector for the users in the state
users$ = this.select(state => state.users);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following.

```
<span>There are {{ (users$ | async)?.length }} users</span>
```